# Javascript varibles across functions

Tags: javascript

As an exercise, I'm writing my code within the same namespace (namespace being sample):

```
if ("undefined" == typeof(sample)) {
    var sample = {};
}

sample = {
    foo : function () {

    },

    bar : function () {

    }
};
```

How do I create a variable within the same namespace which is accessible by all functions?

Comment: What's a "namespace" in this context ?

Comment: The namespace in this case is "sample"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to access a variable inside the sample namespace.  To do this, you declare the variable at the same level as your functions, and from within the functions, you access it using the keyword ***this***

```
sample = {
    myVar:10; // this is your variable
    foo : function () {
        return this.myVar++;  // use this keyword to access it.
    },

    bar : function () {

    }
};
```

**Note**:  If you're creating a function (closure) inside your function, you'll want to create an alias for the this keyword (like _self) so that the context isn't overridden inside your new function.

Comment: `sample.myVar` would be safer than `this.myVar`. The value of `this` can be changed using `call`, `apply`, `bind`, `f = sample.foo; f()`.

Comment: Well, it depends on how you're using it.  I typically use it like this:
 var obj = Object.create(sample);
 to create an instance of the object.  In that case, if you use sample, you're going to be accessing the global object instead of the instance property.   The value of this might change, but that was covered in the Note below when I recommended creating an alias for 'this' before entering the closure.  The same can be said for the cases you mentioned, but good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
(function(){

    //Constructor
    function Sample(name) {
        this.sampleName = name;
    }

    Sample.prototype = {
        foo: function() {
           this.sampleName = "otherSample";
        },
        bar: function() {
           this.sampleName += "anotherSample";
        }
    };

    var sample = new Sample("wow");

})();
```